# Need help for textarea content

Tags: reactjs, jsx, textarea

I am trying to display text from my database. The `<p>` doesn't show the expected newlines but `<textarea>` does.

I want to use it like this `<p>{course.overview}</p>`.

When I use this one `<textarea type="text" placeholder={course.overview} className="form-control color-black overflow:scroll" name="overview" rows="95" disabled/>` it keeps the format.

It's not exactly what I want but it's better than `<p>{course.overview}</p>`.
What can I do?

I tried to use same className in `<textarea type="text" placeholder={course.overview} className="form-control color-black overflow:scroll"  name="overview" rows="95" disabled/>`

with

`<p className="form-control color-black overflow:scroll" >{course.overview}</p>` but it changes nothing.

Pictures for example textarea= https://ibb.co/zSmmHrT AND p = https://ibb.co/1L07Dfk

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean with "it remove the format page" ?

Comment: even with images ? I am trying to display text from my database. When I do a <p>{xxx}</p> it doesn't show the expected newline.
So when in a textarea it displays them

Comment: Ah now its clear to me, thanks. Is your text from the db plain text or html?

Comment: Normally, plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `<p>` tag you could use the `<pre>` tag if it's plain text. Otherwise you would need to convert all your newlines with `<br>`

More about the issue here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Comment: Wow thanks it's better ! is the police can be modify ?

Comment: What do you mean by the police?

Comment: My bad, the font https://ibb.co/BspmYPZ

Comment: You can css that. 
pre {
  font-family: inherit;
}

Comment: Thanks AGAIN ! and one last thing, the text is going out of the screen with a slider, can i change this ? and keep everyting on the same page without slider ?

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */ THANKS :)